# Legality of forced, set charitable giving as a condition of employment

Tags: employment, charity

Is it legal, in a right to work state, for an employer to force charitable giving as a condition of employment? There is no choice in the charity, it is a specific one selected by the company. The amount is non-negotiable, it is predetermined by the company based off of the employee’s pay rate. The company does not allow for it to NOT be automatically deducted from the employee’s paycheck. Then on top of that, the company sponsors other types of charitable giving programs for that same charity but those are of voluntary participation.

Comment: Is this a job you already have, or one you are being offered?

Comment: @RonBeyer and how does that change the legality or otherwise?

Comment: @DaleM It could be part of an agreement you sign before employment, which means you can deny it (employment). If it is something being forced onto an existing employee, that could be different. Either way this depends on the business and where it is located.

Comment: It seems like a pay cut and a complicated way for the company to make a charitable donation. Do you know of a reason the company would be prohibited from making the donation directly? Is this in the U.S.?

Comment: it was in the offer letter of my current job as a condition of employment. The choice was accept it or don't get hired, there was no room to negotiate or defer. It is in the US, in Alabama.

Comment: Is the company itself a non-profit?

Comment: the company is a non-profit

Comment: @GeorgeWhite yes, it seems that could be a better solution, e.g. "The whales have had it really hard this year, so we are cutting all staff salaries by 5% and giving that money to Save the Whales International".